# Reading path of several files from a single file

Tags: python, list, readfile

In part of my code I have a list containing path of several files with different extensions. Something like this:

```py
mylist = ['path1/file1.txt', 'path2/file2.dat', 'path3/file3.txt']
```

I would like to make an external file (let's name it 'extfile.txt') containing the elements of this list and then configure my code in the way to read the list from the file, instead of having the list embeded in the code itself. How should I configure the code?

The reason for this method is I have differnt projects. This code can be used for all of them, and this list is the only part that I need to change. As my actual list is too long, I don't want to change it in the code, I prefer to do it in an external code.

Comment: "I would like (several things)". Which of these are beyond your capabilities? Creating a simple text file? Opening it with Python? Reading its contents?

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to make a configuration file that has these values so you can change the values without having to change the code? Or do you need them on file for some other reason?

Comment: When you say 'call that file', I'm assuming you mean *read* the file - there's no need to write the file as Python and then import it or anything unwise like that, surely?

Answer (score 1):

make a file

```
read.txt
```

Input your values:

```
path1/file1.txt
path2/file2.dat
path3/file3.txt
```

read the file

```
with open('read.txt','r') as my_files:
    x = (my_files.read().splitlines())
```

get the output:

```
['path1/file1.txt', 'path2/file2.dat', 'path3/file3.txt']
```

type of the output:

```
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: Thanks Ioannis. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple.

```
    lines = []
    with open("demofile.txt", "r") as f:
      for line in f:
        lines.append(line)

    # Do whatever you were doing previously with the lines' list...
```